# Connecting from one docker container to another managed by mutagen

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, mutagen

I have mutagen running across two projects. Project A runs on port 1025 and project B runs on port 1027. When I want to connect from project A to project B, I always get curl: (52) Empty reply from server. Previously, when I wanted to do this, I set the url address for project B as http://host.docker.internal:1027.

Whats interesting is that I can connect to http://localhost:1027 from my browser as well as Postman, but when I run curl http://localhost:1027 or curl http://localhost:1025, I get Empty reply from server. Since PHP uses curl internally all calls end the same way. And when I start project B with classic docker-compose up, it works without any problem (curl included).
What is the mutagen alternative for http://host.docker.internal or how can I connect from inside one project to another?

I am using Docker for mac (without compose support) and here is the forwarding path from
mutagen.yml

```
forward:
    nginx:
        source: "tcp:localhost:1025"
        destination: "docker://project-a-mutagen:tcp:nginx:1025"
```

Project B has the same configuration, but with port 1027

Thanks for help

Edit: I managed to get it to work by removing the forwarding session, but I would still like to know how to get it to work with forwarding.

Comment: You mentioned that you use docker-compose, so to connect to a service from the other you should use docker-compose service name as it acts as DNS host name for each container. Ex `http://my-service1` , `http://my-service2`

Comment: That is true, but in this case I am trying to connect between containers in two completely separate projects. E.g. both have their nginx container and do not share the same network

Comment: Why not just create a shared overlay network and attach both projects to it? I believe what you are trying to do is against the isolation that docker sets up by default.